# Calculating the linear model with R

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, scatterplot

I need to calculate the linear model in R, i did the following:

> summary(model)

But what if I wanted to calculate only the first point? A bit stuck with this one... Many thanks!
Here is the code used to create plot itself:

```
> elevation=c(12, 34, 32, 12, 11, 14, 56, 75, 43) 
> snowfall=c(6, 52, 41, 25, 22, 9, 43, 67, 32)
> snowfallElevationPlot = data.frame(elevation=elevation, snowfall=snowfall)
> plot(elevation, snowfall)

> model <-lm(snowfall~elevation, data=snowfallElevationPlot)
> abline(model)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: OK, if I use summary model - it gives me the summary of the whole the data set for elevation and snowfall. I need to calculate it only for first variables in elevation and snowfall

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate?" If you mean using only one data point for regression, that's not possible. If you want to know the predicted snowfall when elevation = 12, then plug the 12 into the regression formula and compute the predicted snowfall.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you mean further. Are you able to give a small example of what you intend?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer per se but I hope this can help you better reframe your question.

The results of your regression are:

```
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = snowfall ~ elevation, data = snowfallElevationPlot)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-11.888  -9.182   1.772   7.112  17.581 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   8.8711     6.6218   1.340  0.22221   
elevation     0.7514     0.1716   4.378  0.00324 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 11.01 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.7325,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.6942 
F-statistic: 19.16 on 1 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.003243
```

The intercept 8.8711 is where the regression line meet with the vertical axis when the predictor (elevation) is zero. The coefficient 0.7514 is the slope of the line. We cannot get a meaningful line with only one data point. All your data contribute information to the line. Below is how they are related to your regression results:

[image]

I am guessing you're asking what is the predicted value of the first data point (elevation = 12, snowfall = 6). In that case, the predicted snowfall can be obtained by the formula:

$\hat{snowfall} = 8.8711 + 0.7514 \times 12$

The answer is 17.888, which is where the red horizontal line hits the vertical axis.

You can also use `model$fit` to export the predicted values as an object:

```
> mypred <- model$fit
> mypred
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9 
17.88816 34.41934 32.91651 17.88816 17.13674 19.39099 50.95053 65.22747 41.18210
```

You'll find the same results at the first position.

I hope this help you answer/revise your question.